# TinyMCE - text direction changes automatically to left-to-right after pressing Enter in H1

Tags: tinymce, right-to-left

In TinyMCE 4, if you:

- change the text direction to RTL (push the right-to-left button)
- now insert some text and make it H1 (Header 1)
- now press Enter
- now type something

you can see that edit direction for some reason is switched back to LTR.

What to do (programmatically) to keep direction RTL after pressing Enter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the editor in RTL mode just set it when you initialize the editor:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#directionality

There is also a plugin to allow the user to switch directions themselves:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#directionality

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the editor to be in RTL constantly. 
I indeed use the Directionality plugin in its default behavior (no modifications) to add both "Right-To-Left" and "Left-To-Right" buttons to the toolbar. The user should to be able to switch to RTL normally with the "Right-To-Left" button and the Editor should stay RTL even if the user uses an H1 paragraph. Unfortunately, like I wrote, it switches back when pushing Enter.
The Editor should go back to LTR only when the user pushes the "Left-To-Right" button.

Comment: I can see what you are saying now - I would report that as a defect via the TinyMCE GitHub issue tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues